# YOLOv8: Optimising for map with confidence and iou in prediction

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, bayesian, optuna

I'm trying to figure out what the best `conf` and `iou` is for the model.pred.

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df= pd.DataFrame()

# Load a model
for i in range(1,105):
  print('epoch: ',i)
  try:
    
    model = YOLO(f'/content/weights/epoch{i}.pt')


    for confidence in np.arange(0.1,0.4,0.02):
      for inter in np.arange(0.1,0.8,0.05):  
        # Customize validation settings
        validation_results = model.val(data='/content/myproject/data.yaml',
                                      imgsz=640,
                                      batch=16,
                                      conf=confidence,
                                      iou=inter,
                                      device='cpu')

        t = pd.DataFrame([{"epoch":i,
                          "conf":confidence,
                          "iou":inter,
                          "map50":validation_results.box.map50}])
        df = df.append(t, ignore_index = True)

    print(df.sort_values(by=['map50'],ascending=False).head(3))
  except:
    pass
```

above is my attempt at trying every combination and sorting this by the highest mean average precision (MAP).

This is slow because it's trying every combination. Maybe a package like Optuna or other Bayesian packages can be used? What would you do to optimise this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer using Optuna.

The following will setup an objective trialling various `iou` and `conf` until it finds the maximum MAP50 score. This will lead to a better understanding of the `iou` and `conf` values and how they affect the map score.

1. Install Optuna

```py
!pip install optuna
```

2. Setup Objective

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Objective:

    def __init__(self):
        self.best_map = 0

    def __call__(self, trial):

        i = trial.suggest_int("epoch", 1, 104)
        confidence = trial.suggest_float("confidence", 0.05, 0.5)
        inter = trial.suggest_float("iou", 0.1, 0.8)
        model = YOLO(f'/content/weights/epoch{i}.pt')
        validation_results = model.val(data='/content/myproject/data.yaml',
                              imgsz=640,
                              batch=16,
                              conf=confidence,
                              iou=inter,
                              device='cpu')

        print(validation_results.box.map50)
        self._map = float(validation_results.box.map50)
        map = float(validation_results.box.map50)
        return map

    def callback(self, study, trial):
        if study.best_trial == trial:
            self.best_map = self._map
            print('NEW BEST MAP: ', self._map)
```

3. start trail

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning) # for log error

import optuna
objective = Objective()

# Setting SEED 
from optuna.samplers import TPESampler
sampler = TPESampler(seed=10)

study = optuna.create_study(
    pruner=optuna.pruners.MedianPruner(n_warmup_steps=10), direction="maximize",
    sampler=sampler
)
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=1000, callbacks=[objective.callback])

print("Best trial:")
trial = study.best_trial

print("  Params: ")
for key, value in trial.params.items():
    print("    {}: {}".format(key, value))
```